# Python IRC bot system uptime

Tags: python, bots, irc

I'm trying to show system uptime in my irc bot. The script I'm using is:

```
   #linux
import os, sys
from datetime import timedelta
from util import hook
import subprocess
import datetime
@hook.command
def uptime_linux(inp,say=None):
    with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
        uptime_seconds = float(f.readline().split()[0])
        uptime_string = str(timedelta(seconds = uptime_seconds))
        say(uptime_string)
# windows

def uptime():
    """Returns a datetime.timedelta instance representing the uptime in a Windows    2000/NT/XP machine"""
    if not sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        raise RuntimeError, "This function is to be used in windows only"
    cmd = "net statistics server"
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, 
          stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    (child_stdin, child_stdout) = (p.stdin, p.stdout)
    lines = child_stdout.readlines()
    child_stdin.close()
    child_stdout.close()
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip()]
    date, time, ampm = lines[1].split()[2:5]
    #print date, time, ampm
    m, d, y = [int(v) for v in date.split('/')]
    H, M = [int(v) for v in time.split(':')]
    if ampm.lower() == 'pm':
        H += 12
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    then = datetime.datetime(y, m, d, H, M)
    diff = now - then
    return diff

@hook.command
def uptime_win(inp,say=None):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        say(uptime())
```

It doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't show. I've looked at the code, I don't see why I'm not able to see it.Maybe it might something small but I don't see it :D. I have the needed modules included, and it still doesn't work :'(. Also I'd want to ask if any of you have easier method to get uptime for windows (I have for linux already).Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried not giving two functions the same name?

Comment: Yes, actually the second def uptime() has other definition in my code, I just changed it for here. It's uptime_win, and still I have no idea why it doesn't work when I do .uptime_win. I've tried doing .uptime_win 1, but again, no idea lol.I've edited my first post with the new definitions.

Comment: Well, you still need to call the function somehow. `if __name__ == '__main__'` is inside a function here, so `uptime_win` won't magically call itself. Maybe you meant to put this `if` at the module level?

Comment: That's strange.I've tried removing it, still doesn't show. Could you please recommend me any system uptime script or function for windows, using different code?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You should do some debugging: make sure the function is actually called, add some diagnostic `print`s in the middle.

Comment: I would suggest looking at http://code.google.com/p/psutil/

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what's wrong right now, but in case it helps a bot I worked on did something similar, maybe you can take a look there:

uptime() at https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~p1tr-dev/p1tr/main/view/head:/plugins/info.py
using _get_output defined at https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~p1tr-dev/p1tr/main/view/head:/lib/plugin.py

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not in the main module so you have to remove `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested on Windows as I don't have a Windows box handy, but using [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) (which is supposed to be cross platform)

```
>>> pid = psutil.Process(1) # get main process (kernel or close to it)
>>> pid
<psutil.Process(pid=1, name='init') at 31222480>
>>> pid.create_time # create_time is effectively system up time (or should be close to it)
1356597946.03
```